# The different icon set into a Easy-data-table for each tr using vuejs

Tags: vuejs3

I want to a icon in easy data table.But it takes same icon for all tr tag.I want a different icon for each tr tag.How to i Code it using vue3

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? Some effort is required from your side.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.